# Bind datagrid using third party API datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `C# 4.5`. I have created a windows application.

As per the project requirement, I need to bind a third-party api response that returns array of `json` objects into a `datagrid`.

I've fetched data using `RestClient` and have converted them to object using `JDynamic` package as

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);                 
dynamic result = new JDynamic(response.Content);
```

Is there any technique I may bind this array of objects as a datasource of gridview?

Also, what if I need to display only certain columns?

**Edit:**

---

The JSON response is something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "username": "pthakur@abc.com",
        "first_name": "Carlos",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Alaiz",
        "gender": "male",
        "addr1": "",
        "addr2": "",
        "state": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "post_code": "",
        "email_id": "pthakur@abcd.com",
        "email_id_alt": "",
        "phone1": "1800777333",
        "phone2": "",
        "photo": "2015-09-09-17-14-29-2015-01-22-06-26-15-400-don-passport-lighting-test 044-3-100pc_pp-ps.jpg",
        "populations": [{
            "id": 8,
            "population_name": "Pop 8"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "username": "shailesh.lakum@abc.com",
        "first_name": "Pedro",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Montero",
        "gender": "male",
        "addr1": "",
        "addr2": "",
        "state": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "post_code": "",
        "email_id": "pedro@spam4.me",
        "email_id_alt": "",
        "phone1": "1800999222",
        "phone2": "",
        "photo": "2015-09-09-17-13-40-2014-10-27-06-59-56-bilde.jpeg",
        "populations": [{
            "id": 8,
            "population_name": "Pop 8"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "username": "mario@abcd.com",
        "first_name": "Mario",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Sanz",
        "gender": "male",
        "addr1": "",
        "addr2": "",
        "state": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "post_code": "",
        "email_id": "mario@xyz.com",
        "email_id_alt": "",
        "phone1": "1800288299",
        "phone2": "",
        "photo": "2015-09-09-17-13-17-2014-10-27-06-28-30-Jim-Smith.jpg",
        "populations": [{
            "id": 7,
            "population_name": "Pop 7"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "username": "pthakur@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "Parikshit",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Thakur",
        "gender": "male",
        "addr1": "",
        "addr2": "",
        "state": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "post_code": "",
        "email_id": "pthakur1@xyz.com",
        "email_id_alt": "",
        "phone1": "1800299200",
        "phone2": "",
        "photo": "2015-09-10-11-52-05-parikshit.jpg",
        "populations": [{
            "id": 8,
            "population_name": "Pop 8"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "username": "nidhi.patel1234@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "Nidhi ",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Patel",
        "gender": "female",
        "addr1": "",
        "addr2": "",
        "state": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "post_code": "",
        "email_id": "nidhi@spam4.me",
        "email_id_alt": "",
        "phone1": "1800200300",
        "phone2": "",
        "photo": "female.jpg",
        "populations": []
    }
]
```

I have created a new class for it as below:

```
namespace DemoAutoLogin
{
    public class patient
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string middle_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string addr1 { get; set; }
        public string addr2 { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string post_code { get; set; }
        public string email_id { get; set; }
        public string email_id_alt { get; set; }
        public string phone1 { get; set; }
        public string phone2 { get; set; }
        public string photo { get; set; }
        public List<Population> populations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Population
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string population_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, what can I do to display the JSON records in grid view?

Comment: Create a custom POCO, (_without_ the columns you want to ignore) that you can deserialize this data into. Deserialize it into a `IENUMERABLE` or `ILIST` of your POCO. You can bind this to your DataGrid. I use [this tool](http://jsonutils.com/) to help me with that.

Comment: @HanletEscaño can I have an example code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You then simply can deserialize from result to the `IEnumerable<patient>`. Use Json.NET for this. the `IEnumerable<patient>` you can bind to the grid.

```
public void BindMyData()
{
    IEnumerable<patient> patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<patient>>(resultAsJson);
    datagrid.DataSource = patients;
}
```

Should work this way..

if you don't have a poco:

```
public void BindMyData()
{
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(resultAsString);
    // if this works, i'm not sure:
    datagrid.DataSource = patients;
}
```

if you can't bin the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` to the grid, you maybe could bind a DataTable.
Add this `ToDataTable` extension:

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> list)
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        if (!list.Any())
            return result;

        var columnNames = list.SelectMany(dict => dict.Keys).Distinct();
        result.Columns.AddRange(columnNames.Select(c => new DataColumn(c)).ToArray());
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var row = result.NewRow();
            foreach (var key in item.Keys)
                row[key] = item[key];

            result.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

and then bind it this way:

```
public void BindMyData()
{
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(resultAsString);
    datagrid.DataSource = patients.ToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Error Cannot use a lamda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispached operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: what type is `result` exactly? Castable to `IEnumerable<T>`? than you could check it before and then cast it like `IEnumerable<object> listResult = (IEnumerable<object>)result`

Comment: Let me post some sample data in question that help you to understand it.

Comment: so the result is a string? or you can get the result as a json-string?

Comment: Json string. And I am converting it to objects.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DemoAutoLogin.patient>>(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: hmm I tested it and for me it works with your sample json-string and your poco. What type is the argument you give with `DeserializeObject`? a  string or the dynamic from JDynamic?

Comment: i think it should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<patient>>(response.Content)`

Comment: Yes. But what id I don't create a class patient and just want to display the objects I create from json string in gridview?

Comment: hmm I think you could only deserialize it to a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` to get a table... - works, too. But if you can bind this to a grid.. I'm not sure if this works. try it :)

Comment: so updated and added the `ToDataTable` - with this it should work binding to your grid, if `IEnumerable<Dictionary<,>>` doesn't work